# Why are SHAP interaction values inconsistent with those from a linear model?

Tags: interaction, boosting, shapley-value

I have fit a gradient boosted regressor to some tabular data.

When looking at dependence plots there are some clear interaction effects e.g. effect of gender on the outcome measure reverses dependent on whether the individual is a patients or a healthy control.

These interaction effects very much visible from the SHAP dependence plots, or from fitting a linear model and examining the interaction term. However when looking at the SHAP interaction values the values are relatively low, and other interaction effects appear much higher (that are not apparent with a linear model or when visualising the data)

What is the explanation for this discrepancy?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide details about the gradient-boosted and linear regression models that you are evaluating, along with SHAP plots and other plots that might provide more background. Without that information it will only be possible to provide generic, relatively useless, answers.